# How to split a string in Ruby into two variables in one line of code?

Tags: ruby, string, split

In Ruby, how can I split a string into two variables in one line of code?

Example:

Goal: Split string `s` into variables `a` and `b`, such that `a` = `'A'` and `b` = `123`.

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "A123" # Create string to split.
=> "A123"

irb(main):002:0> a, b = s.split(/\d/) # Extracts letter only.
=> ["A"]

irb(main):003:0> puts a # a got assigned 'A' as expected.
A
=> nil

irb(main):004:0> puts b # b did not get assigned the split remainder, '123'.
=> nil

irb(main):005:0> b = s.split(/\D/) # Extracts number only.
=> ["", "123"]

irb(main):006:0> puts b # Now b has the value I want it to have.
123
=> nil
```

How can the same result be achieved in one line of code?

Comment: Do your strings always contain only 1 non-digit and then one or more digits?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - No, it contains x non-digits, followed by x digits (always in that order).

Comment: Ok, so the format is very simple and you may use any of the solutions below.

Comment: I don't understand the obsession with doing stuff "in one line of code". In Ruby, newlines can *always* be removed. *Every* Ruby code can be written in one line. But does that make the code better? E.g. in your example: `a = s.split(/\d/); b = s.split(/\D/)`. One line. But does that somehow make it better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways, e.g. [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in this particular case would do:

```
a, b = 'A123'.split(/(?<=\D)/)
#⇒ ["A", "123"]
```

Positive lookahead with a limit of slices:

```
'AB123'.split(/(?=\d)/, 2)
#⇒ ["AB", "123"]
```

By indices:

```
[0..1, 2..-1].map &'AB123'.method(:[])
#⇒ ["AB", "123"]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll accept this answer as soon as the time limit allows me to :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of splitting with lookaheads and lookbehinds, you may `scan` the string to tokenize it into digits and non-digits with `/\d+|\D+/`:

```
"AB123".scan(/\d+|\D+/)
# => [AB, 123]
```

The pattern matches

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `|` - or
- `\D+` - 1 or more chars other than digit.

Comment: Sweet! I find this more readable than the lookahead and lookbehinds. Are there any pros or cons for one method over the other?

Comment: It depends on what strings you receive as input and what you need to get in the end. For the type of strings like you posted, it does not matter. If you get `A123BC345GHJ6768` and you need to split into digit-nondigit tokens, my approach seems the right one, is more straight-forward. You may see [this regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/S7zcQNHeD7).

Answer (score 1):

Another one via [`MatchData#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/MatchData.html#method-i-to_a):

```
_, a, b = * "AB123".match(/(\D+)(\d+)/)
#=> ["AB123", "AB", "123"]

a #=> "AB"
b #=> "123"
```

Comment: The tiniest of details: you could write `a, b = * "AB123".match(/(\D+)(\d+)/).drop(1)`, which also lends itself to chaining.

Comment: Yes, of course. One could write `a, b = * "AB12a3".match(/(\D+)(\d+)/)[1..-1]`, but an exception is raised if there's no match. Depending on one's interpretation of the question, anchors may be needed.